# How to setup DreamPie to mimic Django's "manage.py shell" functionality

Tags: python, django, shell, development-environment, command-line-interface

I would like to use [DreamPie](http://www.dreampie.org/), a python shell, as a CLI that functions the same way that `manage.py shell` works.

Additionally, it would be very nice to have some way to automatically run some code when the shell starts, like a set of import statements.

*If you are unfamiliar with the specifics of getting this to work with DreamPie, I could also appreciate knowing what it is that `manage.py shell` does so I could apply it to another shell environment/interpreter.*

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/HEAD/django/core/management/commands/shell.py

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Django project directory
2. Execute DreamPie there
3. Then copy and paste `manage.py` on DreamPie console replacing `sys.argv` by `['manage.py', 'shell']`